sepfootnotecontent after sepfootnote

This question led to a new feature in a package:
sepfootnotes

With the sepfootnote package, you can separate the footnote mark with the footnote content (in much the same way as footnotemark and footnotetext but better behaved):
    \sepfootnotecontent{key}{Here is the footnote text.}        
    Here is the main text.\sepfootnote{key}


However, you must put the \sepfootnotecontent command before the \sepfootnote.
I would like to be able to have the following code
    Here is the main text.\sepfootnote{key}
    \sepfootnotecontent{key}{Here is the footnote text.}        

and this would compile as before:


It is customary on this site to include an MWE with your question. Often, a question cannot be answered without one, but even in a case like this, where the question is still clear without one, it lowers the barrier for people to look into it and write an answer. That way, you get more and better answers, even without a bounty. ;-)

This answer was turned into the sepfootnotes package option after, available from version 0.3d onwards. See the package documentation or the package author's answer for details.

Original answer:
You can write the footnote definition to the .aux file.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sepfootnotes}

\makeatletter
  \NewDocumentCommand\declarefootnote{ m m }{%
    \write\@auxout{%
      \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\expandafter\gdef
        \csname sepfootnotes@text@sepfoot@#1\endcsname{%
          #2%
          \label{fn:#1}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is the main text.\sepfootnote{key}

\declarefootnote{key}{Here is the footnote text.}

Here is a reference\footref{fn:key} to the footnote.

\end{document}

I created a new macro rather than redefining \sepfootnote to avoid problems with other packages using this macro. I think it's cleaner, but you can also redefine the original macro if you prefer; the risk is pretty low in this case.
Things to keep in mind with this approach:

You cannot re-use keys; they have to be unique in the entire document.
You have to compile twice before the footnote text is correct.


Following your comment I edited the definition to not expand the footnote text before writing to the aux file, so fragile commands should now work as you expect. For your use-case of labeling the footnote for referencing, we can easily add an automatic label using the already present footnote key. Note that this means you cannot use the same footnote more than once, but you probably don't want to do that anyways.

This is great. I just have one complication before accepting your answer: I want to reference the same footnote multiple times. Normally I would do this by writing \sepfootnotecontent{key}{Footnote text \label{footlabel}} and then later when I want to reference the footnote again I would write \footref{footlabel}. But if I try to add a label inside \declarefootnote I get an error.

@James See the edited answer.

@schtandard This is the package author. I'm about to release a new version of the sepfootnotes package implementing your idea by means of an after option. I'd like to acknowledge it in the documentation. Please let me know by email what name I should use, or whether "schtandard" is fine. Thanks

@eduardo.tex Thanks for asking, "schtandard" will be fine, I think, as that's what I go by around here.

Update the sepfootnotes package to version 0.3d, and use the after option, which implements @schtandard's answer above. I'm the package author.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[after]{sepfootnotes}
\begin{document}
Here is the main text.\sepfootnote{key}
\sepfootnotecontent{key}{Here is the footnote text.}
\end{document}

Caveats: (i) must compile twice, (ii) notes will take global scope, and (iii) no warnings will be issued if a key is redefined. (Don't redefine a key. Duplicate definitions will result in footnotes in reverse order.)
Labels and cross-references work as expected, but the document needs to be compiled three times now:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[after]{sepfootnotes}
\begin{document}
Here is the main text.\sepfootnote{key}
See footnote \ref{label}.
\sepfootnotecontent{key}{Here is the footnote text.\label{label}}
\end {document}

